# Solr date range search yielding no results

Tags: solr

I'm having a hard time pinning down why my Solr date range search is not working.  I am building on an existing working search, adding two new fields to assist with accommodation search.

I add the following two fields to the schema - The first is effectively an array of dates, and the second is a single value:

```
<field name="available_checkin_dates" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="available_unit_count" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

I verified that the index document was created and sent to Solr with the two fields populated, but the following search terms yield no results:

```
* AND available_checkin_dates:[* TO NOW]
* AND available_checkin_dates:[NOW TO *]
* AND available_checkin_dates:"2012-08-31T00:00:00.0000000Z"
* AND available_checkin_dates:"2012-08-31T00:00:00Z"
* AND available_unit_count:1
* AND available_unit_count:*
```

Either I'm using the wrong syntax, or the documents didn't get indexed.  I'm having a hard time reading the catalina logs, and I can't find a tool that inspects the actual indexed documents.

Any ideas on how to help me nail this one down?  I'm a relative Solr newbie.

Comment: I now see that if I search:
* AND -available_checkin_dates:[* TO *]
I get all documents back.  I guess I need to review the indexing process, but I can't read enough from the logs to explain why the docs haven't gone through.  Let me check the buffering settings to start with, although I don't think it's that, as it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, there was a problem with the auto-commit settings, so the buffer wasn't getting flushed.  Documents were getting committed with commit as false, but the auto-commit settings weren't in place to flush when the level of uncommitted documents reached a certain number.